# Cannot create application with Grails

Tags: grails

I've downloaded Grails from 
Manual Installation
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.htm

and followed all the instructions there.

But when I ran

```
grails create-app helloworld --stacktrace
```

I got the error:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:3.3.9 in nexus (http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:3.3.9 in nexus (http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:318)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:300)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:292)
        at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:54)
        at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:50)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:333)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:234)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:3.3.9 in nexus (http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue? I've googled it but there aren't many results and the suggested solutions didn't help me.
The one "did nothing" and it started working, and the other suggested cleaning maven repository. I didn't do the last one as I didn't see how a fresh Grails installation is related to installed Maven... However I'm new to Grails.

Maybe a proxy should be set...

Nope. When I tried to set proxy I got:

```
grails add-proxy client --host=<ip> --port=<port>

| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-bom:pom:3.3.9 in nexus (http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

All that happened when I used Grails 3.3.9 on Windows 10

Comment: I would try the maven clean & check you don't have any partial artefacts in your maven repo for org.grails:grails-bom, delete them if you have and try again

Answer (score -1):

Using Grails version 2.5.0 fixed the error for me.

Comment: FYI... There aren't good reasons to create a new Grails 2.5.0 app in 2019.  Grails 3 has been out for almost 4 years.  We put Grails 2 in maintenance mode quite a while ago.  If for some reason you really want to use Grails 2, you probably should use Grails 2.5.6.  Best of luck!